# How would I inherit from an interface in an Abstract class And Implement Virtual Methods

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Here is the F# code I've written so far.  If I add a interface ILogger with underneath

```
type LoggerBase() =  
     interface ILogger with
     // rest of code here ...
```

I end up getting errors... not quiet sure how to inherit from the ILogger interface and  create overridable/virtual methods in the abstract class.

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics

[<Interface>]
type ILog = 
    abstract member Format : string -> string
    abstract member Log : string -> unit

[<Interface>]
type ILogger = 
    inherit ILog 
    abstract member Info : string -> unit
    abstract member Error : string -> unit
    abstract member Warn : string -> unit
    abstract member Verbose : string -> unit 
    abstract member Debug : string -> unit


[<AbstractClass>]
type LoggerBase() = 
        abstract member Log : string -> unit

        abstract member Format : string -> string
        default x.Format(message) = 
            let date = DateTime.Now
            let formatted = date.ToString() + message
            formatted

        abstract member Info : string -> unit
        default x.Info(message) = x.Log("Info | " + message)

        abstract member Error : string -> unit
        default x.Error(message) = x.Log("Error | " + message)

        abstract member Warn : string -> unit
        default x.Warn(message) = x.Log("Warn | " + message)

        abstract member Verbose : string -> unit 
        default x.Verbose(message) = x.Log("Verbose | " + message)

        abstract member Debug : string -> unit
        default x.Debug(message) = x.Log("Debug | " + message)

type NullLogger() = 
    inherit LoggerBase()
    override x.Log(message) = 
        let msg = x.Format(message)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg)
```

Comment: What are the errors you get? (the code seems to work for me)

Comment: When I try and inherit from interface ILogger on the LoggerBase abstract class by putting "interface ILogger with" above the member declarations. I believe F# requires explicit interface declarations but I'm not sure how to do that from within an abstract class.

Comment: I think this might be the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889548/define-an-abstract-class-that-inherits-an-infterface-but-does-not-implement-it

Comment: The existing answer mentioned by @JohnPalmer should answer the question. That said, I would avoid using too much inheritance in F#. Maybe passing the log function as a constructor parameter would be easier...